# R: select all rows that belong to maximum count

Tags: r

In a monitoring scheme each species (A, B, ...) is counted at least twice in each area (a1, a2, ...). For the final result the rows from the sample with the highest total count need to be selected for each area and species.

Example data:

```
data_joined <- data.frame("species"    = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), 
                          "area"       = c("a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a2","a1","a1","a2","a2"), 
                          "sample_nr"   = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), 
                          "count"      = c(1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,3,3))
```

My current solution is pasted below. However, the loop is very slow on the original data which contains about 18,000 rows. I can imagine there are much faster and elegant solutions. The original data are in sf format and include geometries which need to be kept after selection.

```
i_list <- list() # empty list

for (i in unique(data_joined$area)) # all areas that are in the data
{ 
  loop_i_data <- data_joined[data_joined$area == i,] # select data for area i 

  j_list <- list()

  for(j in unique(data_joined$species)) # all species that are in the data
  { 
    loop_j_data <- loop_i_data[loop_i_data$species == j,] # select data of species j in area i 
    max_select <- which.max(                                          
      c(sum(loop_j_data[loop_j_data$sample_nr == "1",]$count, na.rm = TRUE),  # sum first count
        sum(loop_j_data[loop_j_data$sample_nr == "2",]$count, na.rm = TRUE),  # sum second count
        sum(loop_j_data[loop_j_data$sample_nr == "3",]$count, na.rm = TRUE),  # sum third count
        sum(loop_j_data[loop_j_data$sample_nr == "4",]$count, na.rm = TRUE),  # sum fourth count
        sum(loop_j_data[loop_j_data$sample_nr == "5",]$count, na.rm = TRUE),  # sum fifth count
        sum(loop_j_data[loop_j_data$sample_nr == "6",]$count, na.rm = TRUE),  # sum sixth count
        sum(loop_j_data[loop_j_data$sample_nr == "7",]$count, na.rm = TRUE))) # sum seventh count
    j_list[[j]] <- loop_j_data[loop_j_data$sample_nr == max_select,]          # add maximum count occasion to list 
  } 
  i_list[[i]] <- do.call(rbind, j_list)
}
data_final = do.call(rbind, i_list) # rbind all data
row.names(data_final) <- NULL
data_final
```

Comment: `data_joined %>% group_by(species, area) %>% filter(count == max(count))` in `dplyr`

Comment: This is not the solution. I don't need the rows that have the maximum but the rows which belong to the sample_nr which has the highest total sum of column count. Please reopen.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Reopened.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works now and is much faster than my own solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can find the `sum` of `count` for each `species`, `area` and `sample_nr` and select all the rows with max count in each `species` and `area`.

```
library(dplyr)

data_joined %>%
  group_by(species, area, sample_nr) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(count)) %>%
  slice(which.max(n)) %>%
  left_join(data_joined) %>%
  select(-n)

#  species area  sample_nr count
#  <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A       a1            2     6
#2 A       a2            2     1
#3 B       a1            1     1
#4 B       a1            1     1
#5 B       a2            2     3
#6 B       a2            2     3
```